# Angular http.get() JSON into own class

Tags: arrays, json, angular, http

If I define a class with:

```
export class xy {
  name: string;
}
```

And import a JSON with `http.get()` that looks like this:

```
[{"name": "peter"},{"name": "andre"}]
```

How can I convert the JSON into a `xy[]` the easy way? Since both of them have the exact structure. Is there a function for this or do I have to create an own one that copies each element into the `xy` Array?

Greetings

Comment: Please be clear about what exactly are you trying to do? From my understanding, you want an `Array<xy>` and your response from `http.get()` is exactly an `Array<xy>`.

Comment: Am I missing something here? I don't really think you'll have to do anything out of the box to assigning the response to your Component Property or whatever it is that you're trying to assign.

Comment: @Zude, you're question is about serialization or type-checking ? Because you used convert I assumed it was about deserialization, i.e.: the process of converting your raw JSON int JS object instances such as defined in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom deserialization by adding a method to the class and running it in the GET callback, or you can you use a library for that such as [cerialize](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize) for typescript (don't know any great one for JS, I would create manual methods).

Here goes an example :

```
export class Xy {
  name: string;
  static Deserialize(jsonArray) {
    jsonArray.map((json) => {
      const xy = new Xy();
      xy.name = json.name;
      return xy;
    }
  }
}
```

And on the callback, do something like :

```
http.get(...).then((res) => {
  const items = Xy.Deserialize(res);
})
```

Depending on your case, maybe fine tune this with some error handling and property checks..

In case you'd use Typescript, I've been using quite intensively the cerialize library because it allows to use decorators to define the serialization types which cuts a lot of overhead when you have more complex data inheritance and API compatibility requirements. The library handles effortless arrays.
Your example would look something like this :

```
import {serialize} from 'cerialize';

export class Xy {
  @serialize
  public name: string;
}
```

And on the callback of the GET :

```
import {Deserialize} from 'cerialize';

http.get(...).then((res) => {
  const items = Deserialize(res, Xy);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shape is exactly the same you can do this:

```
Object.assign(new xx(), obj);
```

Where `obj` is the result you get from your backend.

The question I have here is, do you really need a class? If xy should only have the fields and no methods on it, you could use an interface instead.

```
interface xx {
    name: string;
}
```

Then you should be able to use `this.http.get<xy[]>('path/to/resource')`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `HttpClient`. It accepts a generic type to the get method:

```
this.http.get<xy[]>('YOUR_URL');
```

Subscribing to whatever is returned from this `get` method will return to you an Array of type `xy`

Make sure to add `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array of your `NgModule` before using this though.

Ideally, you should be having interfaces for Data Models instead of classes. That's what the [**Angular StyleGuide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) recommends:

> Consider using an interface for data models.

Here's a more Concrete Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Todo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  todos: Todo[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Todo[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=1')
      .subscribe(todos => this.todos = todos);
  }
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-generic-http-get?file=src/app/app.component.html) using JSONPlaceholder's Mock Todos Service.

Comment: But i do get a JSON not a xy data. the http.get should read my json. This json has the exact structure of xy but is just a json not a xy. But i want to convert my json import into the xy :s

Comment: I don't think you'll have to worry about it. Notice how I've defined a variable in the above eg named `todos` and declared it of type `Todo[]`. And then in my `Subscription` I'm getting the the todos and I'm assigning it to `this.todos` What I'm trying to point out here is that, you don't have to convert anything. It's something that generics will already take care of. Do have a look at the StackBlitz Sample I've added the link to.

Comment: This method is just for typechecking, youre passing the class into the generic type accepted by the HttpClient, you're not effectively instantiating new instances of the class upon JSON retrieval.

Comment: @Francisco, de-serialization is automatically handled. You don't have to manually do something like `JSON.parse` to deserialize objects here. The type of `todos` in my example above would be Object and not string. That's how it works in JavaScript. Unless I'm missing something crucial here.

Comment: No, you're right, but not fully. De-serialization and serialisation is handled by the angular service from JSON to js objects and vice-versa. But if you want to deserialize from and into derived structures such as a custom class as described in the question, you do need to handle it. Else you'll get an object with a JS Object constructor, not an Xy class constructor.